# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04: Boot hangs just before login screen

Tags: gnome, 14.04, login

I installed Ubuntu Gnome and did a lot of system configurations and installed all my programmes. Now once of a sudden the booting sequence hangs just before the login screen. If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> I will get to the login screen. However, login just ends with a black screen and the desktop does not show.

I looked into https://askubuntu.com/a/223634. Accessed the terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and tried the following:

- `ls -lah` does not show .Xauthority
- `ls -ld /tmp` seems to be okay regarding writing rights
- `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` did not show any results
- Even after killing X and login in, I can find `.xsession-errors`

Can you help me to debug this issue? Thanks.

Xorg.0.log output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7418243/

One line says: `[   337.141] setversion 1.4 failed: Permission denied` Does that hint to anything?

Comment: The classical files to look at are `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (for problems before the login) and `~/.xsession-errors` (after login). How much time are you waiting before killing the X server? Sometime `gnome-shell` dies on the login, and apport blocks my system for more than two minutes trying to collect data --- try a `killall apport` in the Virtual Console. See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1300980

Comment: I can´t find `.xsession-errors` even after login in and landing in the blank. If I do `killall apport` it can not find the process. Please see log ouput above. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new user via the terminal and it turns out I could login with no problem with it. So I just went on and reset my own `~/.profile` by renaming it. I then just had to redo all the gnome settings. Not ideal but it works at least again.

Comment: it's bad but out of desperation, I ended up doing the same - at least it works...